# Use ping in batch file to determine fastest server

Tags: batch-file, ping

I want to ping 2 servers in our company network, and determine which is the fastest (based on the Minimum = [n]ms at the and of a ping). Then do something using the fastest server.

Pseudo code:

```
a = Ping MyServerA
b = Ping MyServerB
if (a < b)
    copy from x to c:\
else
    copy from y to c:\
```

P.S. Please type out a working script, because i really do not understand much about batch file things like: "for /F "tokens=3" %%a in (reg2.txt) do set MyDocs=%%a"

Answer (score 3):

This code get the fastest server in FastestServer variable, so you may use it in any command you wish, i.e. `copy %FastestServer% ...`:

```
@echo off
set MyServerA=127.0.0.1
set MyServerB=127.0.0.2
for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%a in ('ping %MyServerA% -n 1 -w 1000') do set MinServerA=%%a
for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%b in ('ping %MyServerB% -n 1 -w 1000') do set MinServerB=%%b
set MinServerA=%MinServerA:~0,-2%
set MinServerB=%MinServerB:~0,-2%
if %MinServerA% lss %MinServerB% (
    set FastestServer=%MyServerA%
    ) else (
    set FastestServer=%MyServerB%
)
echo Fastest Server: %FastestServer%
```

I hope the code be self-explanatory and will work as expected. If you have any further question, just post it!